# Probability, conditional or binomial

Tags: probability

Q: In a study about the prevalence of HIV in occasional couples, it is observed that the probability that one of the members of the pairs is infected (or both) is 10%. On the other hand, we know that the probability that a person of this population is infected is 6%.

I would like to know what type of probability is this? It seems binomial to me, however, I got suggestions that it might be conditional probability.

A: Probability that both members of couple are infected.

B: Probability that if one member of couple is infected other will also be infected.

C: Is it independent that one subject is infected to say that other is infected?

D: If we select 20 couples, what is the probability that exactly only 4 of them have one infected member?

E: What is the probability that atleast 4 couples have one infected members.

Thank you,

Comment: You wrote that you want to know what type of probability is it (i.e, what distribution), but then wrote a list of specific events. Perhaps clarify the question a bit.

Comment: This is about conditional and joint probability. If $A$ is the event the first individual in the couple is infected and $B$ the even the second individual is infected then the question suggests $P(A)=P(B)=0.06$ and $P(A \cup B)=0.1$.  The questions are then (a) Find $P(A \cap B)$, (b)  Find $P(A \mid B)$, (c) Is $P(A \cap B)=P(A)P(B)$?.  Questions (d) and (e) do involve the binomial distribution

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I am new to this field. As I am confused type of probability. I also need help to understand some of these answers.

Comment: If I can get a little more clearification about D and E will be great. Why is it binomial? How will it be calculated?