# What type of probability and calculation

Tags: probability

Probability of HIV infection in population = 6%

Probability if, one member in couple or both infected = 10%

Q: If we have 20 couples, what is the probability that only 4 couple have one infected member.

Q: atleast 4 couples have atleast 1 infected member.

It seems that binomial distribution

Couple

M F

0 0  (no infected member)

0 1 (one infected)

1 0 (one infected)

1 1 (both infected)

However, I am confused with calculations. Need help to understand calculation.

Comment: same question as your https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3449023/probability-conditional-or-binomial - Did you respond to the comments there?

Comment: Yes, I responded to comments there, as asked by me. Requested to understand the answers of D and E, but unfortunatley did not get any reply. I actually calculated it, but I just want to be sure that my answers are correct.